# AutoCompleteBox is Evil

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, silverlight

Heres the Question:

Why does the AutoCompleteBox hate me??  I've spent at least 3 days trying to get the ACB to display data in the drop down list. All I get is the Class name in the Dropdown list. THe Listbox work Perfectly.

Thank you for your Time and Effort!

Heres a Pic of whats its doing:
[image]

Now heres the XAML for the Listbox

```
    <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="367,81,0,0" Name="ListBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Together}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" sadssa" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here's the XAML for the AutoCompleteBox

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="atcTextBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ValueMemberPath="CountryNumber" FilterMode="StartsWith"
            IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" Height="30" MinimumPopulateDelay="0" MinimumPrefixLength="0" Margin="29,225,259,225">
            <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Together}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

And The Code Behide.

```
Partial Public Class pgMain
    Inherits Page

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim a = GetCountry()
        ListBox1.ItemsSource = a
        atcTextBox.ItemsSource = a
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCountry() As List(Of Country)
        Dim lstCountry As New List(Of Country)()
        lstCountry.Add(New Country() With {.CountryName = "India"})
        lstCountry.Add(New Country() With {.CountryName = "USA"})
        lstCountry.Add(New Country() With {.CountryName = "Australia"})
        lstCountry.Add(New Country() With {.CountryName = "Germany"})
        lstCountry.Add(New Country() With {.CountryName = "England"})
        Return lstCountry
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Country
    Private m_CountryName As String
    Public Property CountryName() As String
        Get
            Return m_CountryName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_CountryName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_CountryNumber As Integer

    Public Property CountryNumber As Integer
        Get
            Return m_CountryNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Together
        Get
            Return m_CountryName & " " & m_CountryNumber.ToString
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        m_CountryNumber = Rnd(Timer) * 100
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try to change {Binding Path=CountryName} and {Binding Path=Together} to {TempateBinding CountryName} and {TempateBinding Together}. If this don't help, revert the changes and try to remove setting ItemsSource from xaml and replace the line atcTextBox.ItemsSource = a with atcTextBox.DataContext = a. Let me know if this helps :).

Comment: Well, TemplateBinding CountryName gives the error, "CountyName was not found in the type 'Control'. If I Remove the ItemSource for the XAML and replace the ItemSource = a to DataContect = a, then the Drop down effect stops working. (IE nothing to display).  On another Note.. I added a Converter to One of the Text Boxes inside the AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate and the Converter is never hit. (Debugged)

Comment: Comment #2: I tried this and it does not work either http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd833083(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Just to make sure: in the link you've posted, DataContext of the control is set in code-behind. Make sure you do the same in your code.

Comment: Found the Answer. 

Themeing was causeing an error in the AutocompleteBox.  I removed the theme and the Autocomplete box is working now.

        <toolkit:Theme ThemeUri="/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BureauBlue;component/Theme.xaml">
        </toolkit:Theme>

Now to see if there is a fix for that.. 

Thanks Lucas and all!

Comment: Ill mark this Answered in the moning(since i have to wait 5 hours) :) unless you want to mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer.

Themeing was causeing an error in the AutocompleteBox.  I removed the theme and the Autocomplete box is working now.

```
    <toolkit:Theme ThemeUri="/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BureauBlue;component/Theme.xaml">
    </toolkit:Theme>
```

Now to see if there is a fix for that..